# Grunt rename not working

Tags: gruntjs, building

My directory structure looks like this:

```
-src/
-----pages/
----------...
-----...
-build
```

My gruntfile contains the following task:

```
copy: {
    all:{
        dest:"<%= builddir %>/",
        src: ["src/**/*.{yaml,yml,py,html,htm,json,css}"],
        rename:function(d, s){return d.replace("src/","");}
    }
},
builddir: "build/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>-<%= date %>",
```

When I run the copy task, it copies all the selected files into the directory containing the package name, version and build date, as expected, but it copies the entire src directory. while I only want to copy the contents of the src directory, so I'm trying to remove `src/' from dest using the`rename`property, which doesn't work for some reason.

I've only started using grunt today, so I might be makiing a rookie mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I think all you need is the `cwd` (current working directory) option. Unless you in fact want to flatten the files into a single directory.

```
copy: {
    all:{
        expand: true,
        dest:"<%= builddir %>/",
        src: ["**/*.{yaml,yml,py,html,htm,json,css}"],
        cwd: "src/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the `flatten` option, which removes the directory structure.

```
copy: {
    all:{
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        dest:"<%= builddir %>/",
        src: ["src/**/*.{yaml,yml,py,html,htm,json,css}"]
    }
}
```

Comment: If I run this, I'm getting an error: `Warning: Unable to write "build/dev2013-0.1.0-2013-12-30T23:53:51.708Z/" file (Error code: ENOENT).`